# how to add variable to 'classname' in jquery using match function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to check the classname with pattern eg. sort-order12, sort-order13 using the match function in jquery. 
The below usage is not working. Anyone can help ?

```
var sort_order = $('.js-data-selector.active:first').data('sort-order');
```

sort_order_next -> is the variable containing integer value.

```
var child = $("table tr td").filter(function() {
  return $(this).prop("class").match(/"sort-order"+(sort_order_next)/)
}).closest("tr");

child.show();
```

I am trying to display the nodes with classname with pattern "sort-order-1", "sort-order-2" etc. according to the node value (sort-order-next) obtained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```js
var sort_order_next = 12;

var child = $("table tr td").filter(function() {
  return $(this).prop("class").match(new RegExp('sort-order-' + sort_order_next));
}).closest("tr");

console.log(child);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="sort-order-12"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="sort-order-13"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="some-cls"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This code works.. !! Thanks for your help Alexander.. !